# Store values of JSON response in arraylist and then filter them according to JSONObject output

Tags: android, json, arraylist

I'm developing an application in which I'm getting `JSON` response when I hit the server with proper parameters. Now, I have to parse those data and store it in the `arraylist`, I'm done till here, but, now I have to parse data and store in `array` according to the `JSONObject`. Here is what I'm trying to say: Following is the `JSON response` which I'm getting:

```
{"rewards":[
{
"rewardID":"2",
"rewardType":"giftcard",
"rewardTitle":"$5 Starbucks Gift Card"
},
{
"rewardID":"3",
"rewardType":"giftcard",
"rewardTitle":"$5 Target Gift Card"
},
{
"rewardID":"24",
"rewardType":"miles",
"rewardTitle":"100 AmericanAirlines Advantage Miles"
},
{
"rewardID":"25",
"rewardType":"miles",
"rewardTitle":"100 US Airways Dividend Miles"
}
]
}
```

You can see `rewardType` parameter which has got different values like `"giftcard"` , `"miles"`. I have to parse according to the `JSONObject` i.e.`rewardType` separately and store it in the `arraylist` for further processing.
Here is what I'm doing for getting resposne and storing it in different variables:

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION,
                HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(
                "API HERE");

        post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        try {
            post.setEntity(new StringEntity("client_id=" + client_id + "&"
                    + "client_secret=" + clientSecretKey, HTTP.UTF_8));

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
            int i = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            System.out.println("HTTP Post status: "
                    + i);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    response.getEntity().getContent()));

            // SB to make a string out of the inputstream
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String line = "";
            String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + NL);
            }
            in.close();

            // the json string is stored here
            String result = sb.toString();
            System.out.println("Result Body: " + result);
            return result;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        JSONObject jObject;
        try {
            jObject = new JSONObject(result);

            JSONArray jSearchData = jObject.getJSONArray("rewards");

            for (int i = 0; i < jSearchData.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject objJson = jSearchData.getJSONObject(i);

                rewardID = objJson.getString("rewardID");
                rewardType = objJson.getString("rewardType");
                rewardTitle = objJson.getString("rewardTitle");

                  if (rewardType == "giftcard") {
                    System.out.println("Reward ID: " + rewardID);
                    System.out.println("Reward Type: " + rewardType);
                    System.out.println("Reward Tittle: " + rewardTitle);
                    System.out.println("Reward ImageFileName: "
                            + rewardImageFilename);
                    System.out.println("Reward Price: " + rewardPrice);
                }

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: now what you want to do

Comment: See my comment on your answer.

Comment: As you have told I'm doing `rewardType=="giftcard"` but nothing is being printed inside the `if` statement. Outside `if` I'm able to print everything. How to filter only those data which has `rewardType=giftcard` as response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

if (rewardType.equals("giftcard"))

Answer (score 0):

if you getting this data from a url then this

```
      HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                    inputstream = httpEntity.getContent();  
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
```

otherwise

```
                    try {

        json = (your full data convert into string).toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }



          rewards = jObj.getJSONArray("rewards");

        // looping through All 
        for (int i = 0; i < rewards.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = rewards.getJSONObject(i);

            // Storing each json item in variable

            rewardID = c.getString("rewardID");
            rewardTitle = c.getString("rewardTitle");


            // adding all get values into array
            if (rewardID != "null" && rewardTitle != "null") {
          //add your data values into list and then filter
                array1.add(rewardID);
                array2.add(rewardTitle);


            }

        }
```

**Edit**

```
    ArrayList<String> array1 = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> array2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> array3 = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (rewardType=="giftcard") {
        array1.add(rewardID);
        array2.add(rewardTitle);
         array2.add(rewardType);
      }

   show in which activity you want to show
```

Comment: I have to show data in an activity only with `rewardType=giftcard`, rest of the things are done.

Comment: As you can see I have four data in the response two have `rewardType=giftcard` and two has `rewardType=miles`. I just want to show data which has `rewardType=giftcard` in my activity. Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: simple, at if condition check rewardType==giftcard then add in array list whole things or sinle item then show in your activity

Comment: Can you edit your answer and provide me a sample code. Because I'm confused. If I do `rewardType=="giftcard"`, so how can I differentiate with the whole response.

Comment: I'm doing this thing: `if (rewardType == "giftcard") {
      System.out.println("Reward ID: " + rewardID);
      System.out.println("Reward Type: " + rewardType);
      System.out.println("Reward Tittle: " + rewardTitle);
     }`

Nothing is being printed on my log. Edit was not helpful.

Comment: I have edited my question, with code. Please answer if you have something else for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create an object to encapsulate the data read from the JSON. IE:

```
public final class Reward {
    private static final String REWARD_TYPE_GIFTCARD = "giftcard";
    private final int mRewardId;
    private final String mRewardType;
    private final String mRewardTitle;

 public Reward(final int rewardId, final String rewardType, final String rewardTitle){
     mRewardId = rewardId;
     mRewardType = rewardType;
     mRewardTitle = rewardTitle;
 }
 // Implement getter methods here.
```

}

You can then have an array list of these Reward objects which will make them a tad easier to work with. You could even add a method that checks if the reward is a giftcard:

```
public boolean isGiftcard() {
    return REWARD_TYPE_GIFTCARD.equals(mRewardType);
}
```

At this point you could do what Rohit suggested and only add it to the list if it's a giftcard.  Lastly, if you still need all of the objects and you are just looking for a logical way to group them, try a HashMap> where the key is the reward type, and the value is a list where you put all of the rewards that isGiftcard() is true for.

Comment: Can you tell me how to achieve that using different class. I have posted my code whatever things I have done so far for this, just filtering is not happening with me.

Comment: Since you accepted another answer, I would assume you are all set then? My answer really only helps you clean up the code a bit (I guess I didn't understand your actual question).